# How to convert 2 strings to a list python?

Tags: python, list

```
a =["['ab','bc','c'],['a','d'],['e']"]
b = []
for i in a:
  for j in i:
     for k in j:
       b.append(k)
print (b)
```

The expected result is `['ab','bc','c','a','d','e']`
but output is

```
['[', "'", 'a', 'b', "'", ',', "'", 'b', 'c', "'", ',', "'", 'c', "'", ']', ',', '[', "'", 'a', "'", ',', "'", 'd', "'", ']', ',', '[', "'", 'e', "'", ']']
```

Comment: Note that your `a` is `list` with single `str`, rather than `list` of `list`s. Operation you try to accomplish is called *list flattening* and there are numerous way to do it, so I suggest you search for them and then use one which fits best your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You have not list of lists, but list with 1 string item, just mistake.

Change to this

`a =[['ab','bc','c'],['a','d'],['e']]`

And then you can use sum function

`sum(a, [])`

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `ast` module

```
import ast
 from itertools import chain
a =["['ab','bc','c'],['a','d'],['e']"]
l = ast.literal_eval(a[0])
output = chain.from_iterable(l)
# ['ab', 'bc', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e']
```